# Docker on Windows: Compiler Runs Out of Heap Space in Containerized Build Environment

Tags: c++, docker, scons

### Context

Our jenkins server (*windows server I think*) is using a windows Docker image to create a build environment to compile our windows applications.

```
FROM 192.168.226.153:8081/docker-images/external-base/windows:1809-KB4592440
```

So far, everything works

### The problem

I am trying to use this Docker Image on my Windows 11 professional desktop, using Docker Desktop for windows.  I can run the command to compile from inside the container `C:\Python38\Scripts\scons.exe --site-dir=C:\3rdParty\devTool\site_scons --pkgroot=C:\3rdParty -j8`, but during the compilation, I have these kind of errors :

```
c:\3rdparty\3rdpartypackages\boost-1.68.0_vs2017\include\boost\spirit\home\qi\auxiliary\eps.hpp(90): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
c:\3rdparty\3rdpartypackages\boost-1.68.0_vs2017\include\boost\spirit\home\qi\directive\omit.hpp(104): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
c:\3rdparty\3rdpartypackages\boost-1.68.0_vs2017\include\boost\function_types\detail\components_impl\arity20_1.hpp(84): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
c:\3rdparty\3rdpartypackages\boost-1.68.0_vs2017\include\boost\spirit\home\qi\directive\omit.hpp(54): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
```

I don't understand because the spec of the computer is high :

- 12th generation I9-12900
- 32 gig of ram
- 16 core
- 24 logical core

### What I tried

- The same Windows 11 machine that hosts the problematic container successfully completes the compilation process when I set up the build environment locally.
- Additionally, an older Windows 10 computer also manages to compile without any issues when the build environment is installed directly on it.

### Questions

- I'm experiencing an issue with my compilation process inside a Docker container on my Windows 11 machine, which isn't occurring on the Jenkins server. There seems to be a misunderstanding on my part regarding Docker's resource allocation for containers.
- Additionally, I've noticed a discrepancy in the behavior of the scons.exe -j8 command when executed inside and outside the container. Outside the container, it's evident that multiple CPUs are in operation. However, when the command is run from within the container, I can't observe the same level of CPU activity.
- Furthermore, after running the scons.exe -j8 command within the container 2-3 times, it appears that the container freezes entirely. The only workaround I've found to exit the container is to initiate a computer restart!
- Could it be possible that I am pushing the intended use of containers beyond their intended capacity or functionality?

Comment: Try running scons with lower `-j` value.  Your current command is expecting 8 way parallel build.  How many CPU's does your container have? How much ram is your container provisioned with?  Likely these are not configured with enough resources for your build..  See: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ for more information on how to specify the docker container provisioning

Comment: @bdbaddog I am confused, the doc says this : "By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows."  I thought my container had access to all the CPUs and all the memory from the host by default.

Comment: Not a container expert, but your error looks like you ran out of RAM... so I'd check the memory in your container and the number of provisioned CPUs..  Does changing to `-j 1` have any impact?

Comment: On Windows, Docker runs in some kind of virtualized environment. What's going on depends on how you set it up. The setup of the VM determines what is exposed to the docker image - so docker can indeed use all of that, but that's not necessarily all of what's physically present on the machine.

Comment: @bdbaddog After digging into this for many hours, just realized that my container is in `hyperv` isolation mode and my container only has 2 cpu and 1 gig of ram.  That explains a lot.  The heap message error is gone with `scons -j1`, but this is very slow and I have others weird compilation errors, it could also be related with `hyperv` isolation mode.

Comment: @MatsWichmann Yes, I realized that I am running in in `hyperv` isolation mode and my container only has 2 cpus and 1 gig of ram.  I can give more with `--cpu-count` and `--memory`, but I still cannot build with `scons -j8`, the container just freeze and I have to restart my computer

Comment: My experience is you can use a little more than the number of available CPUs safely - 2 CPUs suggest you can use -j2 and maybe -j3 will be a slight improvement. The test runner now has an option to try to calculate a usable -j value by accepting "-j 0", that hasn't made it to scons itself yet (if ever).  No application should ever be able to get you into a state where you have to reboot, that's disappointing. scons does let you produce memory stats, but probably you wouldn't get the info in time, if it's going the freeze.

Comment: Also 1GB of RAM in the container is likely far from sufficient.  Can you adjust it upwards? Try at least 8GB (or 16GB), and likely more if you're using MSVC and -J8.  For -J8 (as @MatsWichmann sugguest), you really need your container to have 8 CPUs.